# Validate Min/Max length of Password

Tags: .net, regex

I'm pretty new to Regex, only just started learning it in school. I got my first assignment and am getting through it fairly well.

Let me explain so my code makes sense...
The assignment is making my .NET Regex Tester search through a text for passwords.
These passwords can not contain any whitespaces (so I used `\S`) Can't start with a number or Underscore, so I used `(?m:^([^_|^0-9]{1})`
Can't end on two different characters

```
(?<finalTwo>(?i:\S{1}))(?i:\<finalTwo>)
```

Have to contain at least one digit, so I used a lookahead.
Now, the thing here is, the code is a pretty cluttered thing right now.

```
(?=.*\d)(?m:^([^_|^0-9]{1})(\S*)(?<finalTwo>(?i:\S{1}))(?i:\<finalTwo>))
```

And I have to add one more thing, the password has to be between 8 and 20 characters long.
I know I have to use `{8,20}` (I think), but the thing is, no matter where I enter this, it completely kills the search.

Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disclaimer, that's a pretty long answer!]

I will begin with the character limit.

You'll have to use `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` to indicate the beginning and end of the password and use `\S{8,20}` for the actual password:

```
(?m)(?<!\S)\S{8,20}(?!\S)
```

As you probably already know `(?m)` is for multiline (`^` and `$` matches beginning and end of line respectively instead of the string in this mode).

`(?<!\S)` makes sure there's no non-whitespace character before the password.

`(?!\S)` makes sure there's no non-whitespace character after the password.

Now we add some restrictions:

Cannot begin with number or underscore: `(?![0-9_])` a negative lookahead at the start of the password:

```
(?m)(?<!\S)(?![0-9_])\S{8,20}(?!\S)
```

Must contain at least one digit: `(?=\S+[0-9])` a positive lookahead at the start of the password:

```
(?m)(?<!\S)(?![0-9_])(?=\S+[0-9])\S{8,20}(?!\S)
```

Must end with the same characters: You'll have to capture the second to last character and use a backreference. You can change the `\S{8,20}` part to `\S{6,18}(\S)\1` for this:

```
(?m)(?<!\S)(?![0-9_])(?=\S+[0-9])\S{6,18}(\S)\1(?!\S)
```

Now that should be good.

---

To your regex now:

```
(?m:^([^_|^0-9]{1})
```

First, the {1} is redundant because if you remove it, it wouldn't change anything at all.

```
(?m:^([^_|^0-9])
```

Second, you have unbalanced parentheses. Not sure what's that supposed to be, but I guess the first paren wasn't intended.

```
(?m:^[^_|^0-9])
```

Next, the character class `[^_|^0-9]` matches any character except `_`, `|`, `^` or the range `0-9`. I'm sure that a password *can* begin with `|` or `^`. The metacharacter `|` loses its meaning in a character class! You could use this: `[^_0-9]` instead and this would become:

```
(?m:^[^_0-9])
```

It's okay to use this, but you will have to keep in mind that this is the first character in the password; for you have a range of 8 to 20 characters to respect, and it just changed to 7,19. The only thing left with it is that it also accepts a space. You can put one in the character class to avoid this:

```
(?m:^[^_0-9 ])
```

Okay, looks better now, next one:

```
(?<finalTwo>(?i:\S{1}))(?i:\<finalTwo>)
```

First is a named capture group, okay, with a non-capture group with case insensitivity mode on (not quite necessary since we don't have any alphabets in the regex) and `\S{1}` inside that non-capture group. Once again, the `{1}` is redundant. Removing it and the `(?i)` mode, this becomes:

```
(?<finalTwo>\S)(?:\<finalTwo>)
```

That's not so bad, if it matches the last two character, it'll indeed work.

```
(?=.*\d)
```

Works well. You might want to lookout for the characters other than `0-9` that `\d` matches, but if you don't mind, that works almost; it'd be better to use `\S` instead of `.` here just in case there are two passwords separated by a space next to each other in the text and this might make things go not like you intended.

```
(\S*)
```

That part's more or less okay. There's just no limit imposed.

```
(?=\S*\d)(?m:^[^_0-9 ])(\S*)(?<finalTwo>\S)(?:\<finalTwo>)
```

Okay, now, remember that `(?m:^[^_0-9])` took one character, and `(?<finalTwo>\S)(?:\<finalTwo>)` takes two characters, for a total of 3. The limit you thus impose is:

```
(?=\S*\d)(?m:^[^_0-9 ])(\S{5,17})(?<finalTwo>\S)(?:\<finalTwo>)
```

It almost works, and you only need to put something to prevent partial match of longer passwords. You can usually use word boundaries `\b` but nothing has been mentioned about symbols, so it's safer to assume that a password like `$@4*&AUn++` is also allowed and that's where the word boundaries will fail. That's why I suggest the use of the negative lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
^(?!^[^0-9]+$)[^0-9_].{5,17}(.)\1$
```

`^`: start-of-string.

`(?!^[^0-9]+$)`: Make sure there is a digit by ensuring that the password isn't just a combination of non-digit characters.

`[^0-9_]`: Make sure it starts with something that is not a digit or underscore.

`.{5,17}`: Match any character between 5 and 17 times.

`(.)`: Match the character just before the last one, and capture it in group 1.

`\1`: Make sure the last character is the same as the one before it.

`$`: End-of-string.

`[^0-9_]`, `(.)` and `\1` take up 3 characters, this leaves 5 characters as minimum for `.{5,17}` and hence the `5` as the minimum boundary, and hence 17 as the upper boundary which makes a total maximum of 20 characters.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qX9fN0)

I Know the demo uses PHP, but it doesn't really matter here.